# Elasticsearch meaning must using with multimatch

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a code

```
GET /news/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "multi_match": {
              "query": "France and Luxembourg",
              "fields": [
                 "stkno",
                 "tag",
                 "content",
                 "htext"
              ],
              "operator": "and"
           }
        },
        {
           "range": {
              "CDate": {
                 "gt": "2017-05-23T14:02:11",
                 "lte": "2017-05-24T23:59:59"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 },
    "from": 0,
       "size": 100,
    "sort": [
  {
     "CDate": {
        "order": "desc"
     }
  }
  ]
 }
```

After using the command above, hits total is 2 records. But one have exactly word 'France and Luxembourg', another ones only 'France'.

my question as below:

1. already using 'must', why no showing only exactly word 'France and Luxembourg'?
2. what purpose of operator? i already read it t elasticsearch, but really not understand, can you explain more?

reedit:

i have tried using coding as below, but result become empty.`enter code here`

```
POST _search
 {
   "query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "term": {
              "stkno": "France and Luxembourg"
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "tag": "France and Luxembourg"
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "context": "France and Luxembourg"
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "htext": "France and Luxembourg"
           }
        }
     ],
     "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
  }
  }
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min), when you use `multi-match` and `and` operator, it is a multi match of fields. So your query becomes

```
 (+stkno:France +stkno:and +stkno:Luxembourg)
| (+tag:France +tag:and +tag:Luxembourg)
| (+context:France +context:and +context:Luxembourg)
| (+htext:France +htext:and +htext:Luxembourg)
```

For exact match, you can use the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query).

You can change your `multi-match` section alone into another bool query

```
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "stkno": "France and Luxembourg"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "tag": "France and Luxembourg"
                                        }
                                   },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "context": "France and Luxembourg"
                                        }
                                   },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "htext": "France and Luxembourg"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "minimum_should_match": 1
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: i have tried your recommend coding.. But i can't get my result. Total hits is 0. I copy the value from elasticsearch, it still can't find

Comment: coding too long i cant paste at here

Comment: coding like: POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {   ( follow the coding above u giving) }}

Comment: Can you paste the original document in the question

Comment: Can you paste the original document. Just use GET _search and post the document that should be matching the query